# Where is this color node?

Tags: node-editor, pynodes

I don't know how to put a color node with the chromatic gradient[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTlKB.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### RGB node

It's the usual RGB node you can find under the "Input" submenu, but the owner of the file is using a different Color Picker Type.

You can change the type from the User Preferences Panel.

[image]

The type in the provided images is

```
Square (SV+H)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!